# sass-maven-plugin using add_import_path option

Tags: maven, sass, maven-plugin

Is it a way to use **add_import_path** option in maven plugin configuration or I had to use compassConfigFile ?
Setting **buildDirectory** to the path where are import files is a solution ?

I use this plugin :

http://www.geodienstencentrum.nl/sass-maven-plugin/update-stylesheets-mojo.html

Error :

```
 failed: File to import not found or unreadable: theme.
 Load paths:
```

And I don't have the directory I need in Load paths

I tried

```
 <sassOptions>
         <load_paths>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/theme/colors/red</load_paths>
 </sassOptions>
```

without success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the `load_paths` as an array, this seems to work for me:

```
 <load_paths>['${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/theme/colors/red']</load_paths>
```

The thing that makes it work is the `[ ]` around the string, making it an array it seems in the ruby-end of things, so the sass gem gets it the way it wants

Comment: I didn't try because I changed plugin to use nodejs, guglp... any way tnak you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

So I found a solution

```
<configuration>
<sassOptions>
    <always_update>true</always_update>
    <style>${sass.OutputStyle}</style>
</sassOptions>
<useCompass>true</useCompass>
<compassConfigFile>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/style/config.rb</compassConfigFile>
<resources>
    <resource>
        <source>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/style/themes/colors/cyan</directory>
        </source>
        <destination>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/style/themes/colors/cyan</destination>
    </resource>
    <resource>
        <source>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/style/themes</directory>
        </source>
        <destination>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/style/themes/colors/cyan</destination>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

The first resource load scss files for import in the second resource imported files are avaible. First resource generate nothing in destination but node is needed.